# Loosing posted data when redirecting - php

Tags: php, redirect, post, curl

I don't where I am going wrong. I am sending from the homepage data via an ajax request to somepage.php. Under some conditions, somepage.php redirects the user to someotherpage.php that display the user page. The redirection is made by a header('location :'. $url), (so $url processes someotherpage.php) The problem is that the redirection looses the data that are posted from the initial ajax request. So I choose to tredirect the user via :

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
exit;
```

The problem is that I have no post data anymore when hitting someotherpage.php. Someone could help ?

Answer (score 1):

POST only lasts for one request, so you'll definitely lose it on redirection.

Assign it to a SESSION variable on redirection instead:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['post_data'] = $_POST;
// Redirect the user
```

Then, on the redirected to page:

```
$data = $_SESSION['post_data'];
unset($_SESSION['post_data']);
```

Comment: In fact I am no redirecting anymore, I checked $data is containing the right informations. What $data is becoming when attached to curl process ??

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. If you're not redirecting anymore, $data should work as is. cURL shouldn't affect it.

Comment: I put exactly the code of my post. Then I ran var_dump($_POST);exit; and the output was : array(0) { } ???

Comment: That means nothing was posted to the page in the first place.

Comment: I put the following and it worked $data = $_POST['data'];
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
var_dump($data);exit; so I don't really understand

Comment: You might want to update your post with more relevant code, as I'm not sure what you're doing/have done now.

Answer (score 0):

Your question already have answer in it's own.

Once page is redirected posted data will also gone.

To get posted data globally you must use `$_SESSION` to store posted data. Because as you know `$_SESSION` is super global in it self.

Comment: In fact I am no redirecting anymore, I checked $data is containing the right informations. What $data is becoming when attached to curl process ??